# The sum of two forces is 18 N and resultant whose direction is at right angles to the smaller force is 12 N The magnitude of the two forces are

Tags: vector-spaces

Problem :

The sum of two forces is 18 N and resultant whose direction is at right angles to the smaller force is 12 N The magnitude of the two forces are

(a)  13,5

(b) 12,5

(c) 14,4

(d) 11,7

My approach  :

We can take two forces as $|P| ; |Q|$ as per the given condition

$|P| +|Q| =18N $ ( sum of two forces)  ; $ |R| = |P+Q| = 12 N $

angle formed by smaller force is at $90^{\circ}$.. Please suggest how to go further from here... thanks..

Comment: This problem is poorly worded.  It sounds like the forces are supposed to be vectors but the problem begins "The sum of two forces is 18 N", which is a scalar.  In your approach you are interpreting the start of the problem to mean the sum of the _magnitudes_ of the two forces is 18N.  I'm blaming the author of the problem, not necessarily you.  Fortunately the question is multiple choice so if you get an answer that matches a choice it is likely you interpreted the problem in the intended manner.

Comment: You might try converting all the equations and facts you've written down into equations involving dot products: $\sqrt{P\cdot P}+\sqrt{Q\cdot Q}=18$, $(P+Q)\cdot(P+Q)=144$, $P\cdot(P+Q)=0$. Then see if you can find some useful algebraic manipulations of these equations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the problem is poorly worded.  the two forces are $F1$ and $F2$.  The vector labeled Sum is their sum.  We have $|F2|^2=|Sum|^2+|F1|^2=144+|F1|^2$ and I believe you are supposed to assume $|F1|+|F2|=18$ with solution $|F1|=13,|F2|=5$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: showing vectors P, Q and their resultant R at right angles with P]
Let $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ be the two force vectors and $\mathbf{R}$ be the resultant. Let angle made by $\mathbf{R}$ with $Q$ be $\alpha$. Now, you can resolve $\mathbf{P}$ and $\bf Q$ along and perpendicular to $\bf R$:
$$R=Q\cos(\alpha)+\underbrace{P\cos(90^\circ)}_{=0}$$
$$0=Q\sin(\alpha)-P\sin(90^\circ)$$
Thus, you have $R=Q\cos(\alpha)$ and $P=Q\sin(\alpha)$. You are given $R=12$ and $P+Q=18$.

There are many ways to go from here, you may square and add to get $R^2+P^2=Q^2$ and since $P+Q=18$, you may guess that $P=5$ and $Q=13$ work. Otherwise, you can manually solve as follows.

Divide the two equations to get $P=12\tan(\alpha)$ and so
$$12\tan(\alpha)+12\sec(\alpha)=18$$
$$\sec(\alpha)+\tan(\alpha)=\dfrac32$$
Taking reciprocals,
$$\sec(\alpha)-\tan(\alpha)=\dfrac23$$
Adding gives $\sec(\alpha)=\dfrac{13}{12}$ from where we get
$$Q=12\sec(\alpha)=13$$
and so $P=5$ giving option $\boxed{\bf A}$ as the correct one.

Hope this helps. :)